# Fino a quando è stata in uso la desinenza -a per la prima persona singolare dell'imperfetto indicativo?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, history, tenses

Ecco l'incipit del racconto *Il pugno chiuso*, di Arrigo Boito (nella versione edita da Liber Liber):

> Nel settembre del 1867 viaggiavo in Polonia per certa missione medica che mi era stata affidata; doveva fare delle ricerche e degli studi intorno ad una fra le più spaventose malattie che rattristano l’umanità: la *plica polonica*.

La prima volta che ho letto questa frase, l'oscillazione tra le desinenze -*o* e -*a* per la prima persona singolare dell'imperfetto indicativo mi ha lasciata un po' perplessa. Poi mi sono subito ricordata che Dante utilizzava questa desinenza  -*a* e che era anche stata usata in passato da altri autori.

In effetti, Serianni, nella sezione XI.72.b) del suo *Italiano*, spiega:

> Imperfetto. La desinenza originaria della  persona era -*a*– anche nelle altre
>   coniugazioni – secondo l'etimo latino (AMĀBAM>[*io*] *amava*). Il tipo (*io*) *amavo*, analogico sulla 1ª persona del presente indicativo, si diffonde molto presto nel fiorentino (fine del XIV secolo: cfr. MANNI 1979: 146), ma stenta ad essere accolto nella lingua letteraria; un impulso notevole al suo successo venne dal Manzoni
>   che lo adottò larghissimamente nella seconda edizione dei *Promessi Sposi* (cfr.
>   SERIANNI 1986b: 46-47).

E, infatti, nelle [*Regole grammaticali della volgar lingua*](https://books.google.es/books?id=8hGJAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=imperfetto&source=bl&ots=dqQ6MaxbyU&sig=ACfU3U3JKhAX1aMCZWrQpKXIKs9iJrHfhg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilvY6HxMDpAhWJ8eAKHWecDuoQ6AEwAnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=imperfetto&f=false) di Giovanni Francesco Fortunio (1516) si può leggere:

> Alcuni fanno terminare in o la prima persona dell'imperfetto indicativo di tutti i verbi, come *andavo*, *cantavo*, *amavo*, *parlavo*, *vedevo*, *dicevo*, *leggevo*, *scrivevo*, *avevo*, *i' ero*, ma questo uso non è osservato da alcuno dei nostri buoni scrittori, dalle cui orme non ci si deve allontanare.

Ho avuto l'opportunità di parlare di questo racconto con un gruppo di persone e una di loro, come risposta alla mia osservarzione sul fatto che ho appena spiegato, ha detto che gli sembrava che, nel momento in cui fu scritto (fu pubblicato per la prima volta nel 1870), la desinenza -*a* per la prima persona singolare dell'imperfetto indicativo era ancora in uso. Inoltre, ha fatto il commento che l'aveva infatti usato anche Manzoni nelle prime edizioni di molte delle sue opere, che poi però aveva riveduto cambiando -*a* in -*o* in molti casi.

La mia domanda è: veramente questa desinenza si usava ancora nel 1870? Fino a quando è stata in uso?

Comment: Quando ho scritto "parlare" mi riferivo a "parlare" in senso proprio: miracoli delle nuove tecnologie grazie a una iniziativa della rete di biblioteche pubbliche di Barcellona.

Comment: Per quanto ricordo, Leopardi usava *sempre* la desinenza “-a”. Credo che non sia difficile trovare esempi anche dell'inizio del XX secolo.

Comment: Hai ragione, @egreg: ne parla questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/giacomo-leopardi_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/).

Comment: E se il "doveva" si riferisse alla missione?

Answer (score 2):

Nel libro [*Storia linguistica d’Italia dall'Unità a oggi*](https://books.google.es/books?id=drmMDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT230&lpg=PT230&dq=%22D%27imperfetto+desinenza&source=bl&ots=KONGaaVUQ3&sig=ACfU3U1P3fVC_6p4iXMUB0U6ug0PdHF8Qg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqrbKygbvpAhXBA2MBHYXfB9EQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22imperfetto%20desinenza&f=false), di Tullio De Mauro, si trova che, nella lingua scritta, ci sono state oscillazioni tra le desinenze -*o* e -*a* per la prima persona dell'imperfetto indicativo fino ai primi decenni del Novecento:

> Il caso più cospicuo di rideterminazione è la sostituzione di -*vo* alla desinenza -*va*
> di 1ª persona dell'imperfetto (lat. volg. -*ba*[*m*]), che aveva resistito nella lingua
> letteraria. La desinenza -*vo*, originaria probabilmente della Lucchesia (G. Perale, B.
> Migliorini, *L'imperfetto dell'indicativo*, LN 2, 1940, pp. 139-143), si diffuse prima
> nel linguaggio familiare, poi, sull'esempio del Manzoni (esempio non costante però: cfr. per es. *PS* 509, 18 «m'era proposto»), anche nella lingua scritta, con oscillazioni durate sino ai primi decenni del Novecento (Goidànich *Grammatica* 123; Migliorini *Storia* 707). Base della rideterminazione è l'analogia con il rapporto valido nel presente tra -*a*: -*o* (*canta*: *canto*); sulla parte avuta in genere dai processi analogici nel costituirsi del sistema desinenziale italiano, cfr. Durante *Desinenze*.

Per fare un esempio di questo fenomeno, nella [*Civiltà dei traduttori*](https://books.google.es/books?id=6pX45tPKZt8C&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=%22D%27imperfetto%22+imperfetto+desinenza&source=bl&ots=YhhU-sZvz1&sig=ACfU3U1p6Y-btXWWdoX2L8JQhOZT-szCFg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqrbKygbvpAhXBA2MBHYXfB9EQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22imperfetto%22%20imperfetto%20desinenza&f=false) di Nunzio Ruggiero, si legge che tali oscillazioni si riscontrano nelle traduzioni di Zola che [Ferdinando Bideri](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ferdinando-bideri_%28Dizionario-Biografico%29/) fece nel primo Novecento.

Anche questa risposta della [*Crusca per voi*](http://nencioni.sns.it/fileadmin/template/allegati/QuesitiRisposte/1994_08/1994_8_Risposta_10.pdf) riporta:

> La risposta è semplice: la desinenza -*a* di *io lodava* continua nel fiorentino antico quella del latino *laudabam* e tale permane nei grandi classici del nostro Trecento, Dante, Boccaccio e Petrarca. Nel Quattrocento, forse per influenza del toscano lucchese e senese, entra, in scritti di autori più popolari (Pulci, Berni, Cellini) la desinenza -*o*, analogica a quella del presente; segno di una infiltrazione per via appunto popolare. Analogica come fu la desinenza in -*i*
> della seconda persona, sempre formata su quella del presente indicativo (*tu lodi*) o del passato remoto (*tu lodasti*). Era naturale che all'uscita in -*a* restassero fedeli gli scrittori non toscani, i quali seguivano il modello linguistico dei sommi trecenteschi fiorentini e non sentivano, come i cinquecentisti nati a Firenze, l'influenza della lingua parlata nella loro città. La poesia di
> tono aulico conserva quell'uscita in -*a* fino alle soglie del Novecento (D’Annunzio), mentre nella prosa Manzoni, adeguando la seconda edizione dei *Promessi sposi* (1840-42) all'uso corrente del fiorentino non vernacolare, muta in -*o*, salvo rarissime eccezioni, le desinenze in
> -*a* della prima (1825-27), contribuendo fortemente, nella lingua scritta, alla generalizzazione
> della paradigmatica odierna. Dico nella lingua scritta perché a me è toccato, non molti anni fa, di ascoltare il discorso di un personaggio politico di non comune livello culturale, il quale, parlando in prima persona, si lasciava sfuggire, da vecchio piemontese, la desinenza -*a* negli imperfetti, senza che io, più vecchio di lui, ne soffrissi come di un errore grammaticale, perché essa era presente, e vorrei dire viva, nella mia memoria letteraria. Non è mai troppo
> raccomandabile la pratica di leggere libri di tutte le età della nostra letteratura, per abituarci a non fare oggetto di meraviglia parole e forme diverse dal nostro uso odierno, ma a considerarle segni inevitabili della sua vitalità plurisecolare e frutto, talvolta, di istanze culturali. È meglio stupirci, come di un miracolo, del fatto che, nonostante le vicende e le modificazioni che ha subito nella sua lunghissima vita, la nostra lingua è rimasta per quasi otto secoli tanto uguale, tanto se stessa da consentirci di leggere senza troppa difficoltà la *Divina Commedia*, composta quasi sette secoli or sono.

Un esempio di quello sopra menzionato è la poesia [*La capra*](https://online.scuola.zanichelli.it/letterautori-files/volume-3/pdf-online/37-saba.pdf) di Umberto Saba, in cui appare "sentiva" per "sentivo":

> Ho parlato a una capra.
>
>              
> Era sola sul prato, era legata.
>
>              
> Sazia d'erba, bagnata
>
>              
> dalla pioggia, belava.
>
>
>              
> Quell'uguale belato era fraterno
>
>              
> al mio dolore. Ed io risposi, prima
>
>              
> per celia, poi perché il dolore è eterno,
>
>              
> ha una voce e non varia.
>
>              
> Questa voce sentiva
>
>              
> gemere in una capra solitaria.
>
>
>              
> In una capra dal viso semita
>
>              
> sentiva querelarsi ogni altro male,
>
>              
> ogni altra vita.

Comment: Grazie al commento di @egreg ho avuto l'idea su cosa cercare.